# Betta at bottom of tank

Tags: fish, aquarium, betta

My male betta Drake which I have had for around a year continually sits at the bottom of the tank. He occasionally rushes to the top of the tank to presumably get air. I am aware that my Tetra Floating Starter Kit 1.5 Gallon Cube isn't a entirely suitable tank, that's not permanent. I have the included filter, and a 2-15 gallon heater that keeps the tank at 76°F/24.5°C.

A likely cause is ammonia toxicity, I have yet to cycle any new tank, this will change also.

The bottom is aqua culture aquarium gravel, with aqua culture plants for decoration, Drake usually is at the bottom near or behind these plants. It seems as if whenever I leave the room and return, he moves along the bottom slightly. The real question is if his symptoms are of any cause that is preventable at this time.

[image]

Comment: What is the ammonium level? If it's anything above 0 you need to act fast (change water, move the fish to another aquarium). I can't recognize anything on the image.

Comment: I've already changed the water, and added SafeStart and he has very much improved(Also I dechlorinate). Yet he still loves hanging around the top behind a plant.